# Separate lists stored in a variable using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

How can I transform

```
list = [[68.0], [79.0], [6.0]],  ... [[176.0], [120.0], [182.0]]
```

into

```
result = [68.0, 79.0, 6.0, 8.0], ... [176.0, 120.0, 182.0]
```

Comment: What should the result look like?

Comment: for example, I need individual lists from variable 'list' like this:
      `list1 = [68.0, 79.0, 6.0, 8.0, 61.0, 88.0, 59.0, 91.0]`

Comment: @towi, I would like to point out that original question was not only about to flatten out sublists but also to map them as well so that individual lists can be indexed out as required.

Comment: @Ibe Oh? I could not see that from your original formulation. I am sorry -- but feel free to correct my correction. I can not see what you are driving at.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've correctly understood what `input_lists` should actually look like, then I think what you're after is creating a dict so that `dict[n]` is your nth list. eg: the following code:

```
input_lists = [[[68.0], [79.0], [6.0], [8.0], [61.0], [88.0], [59.0], [91.0]],
       [[10.0], [11.0], [9.0], [120.0], [92.0], [12.0], [8.0], [13.0]],
       [[17.0], [18.0], [13.0], [14.0], [12.0], [176.0], [120.0], [182.0]]]


lists = {i:[el[0] for el in v] for i, v in enumerate(input_lists, start=1)}
# {1: [68.0, 79.0, 6.0, 8.0, 61.0, 88.0, 59.0, 91.0], 2: [10.0, 11.0, 9.0, 120.0, 92.0, 12.0, 8.0, 13.0], 3: [17.0, 18.0, 13.0, 14.0, 12.0, 176.0, 120.0, 182.0]}
```

Comment: It gave error: TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable.
sublists are not separated by commas and no outer brackets.

Comment: I first append the variable to a list within a for loop and then used your `lists` argument outside loop to separate lists. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

```
z = []
for x in list:
    for i in x:
        z.append(i)
```

Comment: `z = [i for x in list for i in x]` would be simper and more concise for that.

Comment: I wrote this answer taking in consideration that person who asked the question might be a beginner. This would be easy to read for him.

Answer (score 1):

Am I missing something or a simple list comprehension would do? And also [`list`](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) is a keyword in python PLEASE DO NOT name your variables which create conflict with python keywords. It will bite you in places you cant imagine.

```
>>> mylist = [[68.0], [79.0], [6.0], [8.0], [61.0], [88.0], [59.0], [91.0]]
>>> [i[0] for i in mylist]
[68.0, 79.0, 6.0, 8.0, 61.0, 88.0, 59.0, 91.0] #this can be assigned to a new list var mylist1
```

**UPDATE:** Based on what lbe said, changing the approach -

```
>>> mylist =[[[68.0], [79.0], [6.0], [8.0], [61.0], [88.0], [59.0], [91.0]],
...        [[10.0], [11.0], [9.0], [120.0], [92.0], [12.0], [8.0], [13.0]],
...        [[17.0], [18.0], [13.0], [14.0], [12.0], [176.0], [120.0], [182.0]]]
>>> [i[0] for i in reduce(lambda x, y: x+y, mylist)]
[68.0, 79.0, 6.0, 8.0, 61.0, 88.0, 59.0, 91.0, 10.0, 11.0, 9.0, 120.0, 92.0, 12.0, 8.0, 13.0, 17.0, 18.0, 13.0, 14.0, 12.0, 176.0, 120.0, 182.0]
```

Comment: The only problem is that this list is part of a for loop so if I try your suggestion then mylist[0] returns: 
`68.0`
`10.0`
`17.0`
not a horizontal list as I provided above .

Comment: @lbe: so you simply replace mylist by mylist[0] in the above code

Answer (score 0):

First, the code above is invalid syntax. You need surrounding brackets or something similar.

#### Possibility one:

```
list =[[[68.0], [79.0], [6.0], [8.0], [61.0], [88.0], [59.0], [91.0]],
       [[10.0], [11.0], [9.0], [120.0], [92.0], [12.0], [8.0], [13.0]],
       [[17.0], [18.0], [13.0], [14.0], [12.0], [176.0], [120.0], [182.0]]]
```

Then `list[0]`, `list[1]`, etc. refer to the sub-lists.

#### Possibility two:

```
list =[[68.0], [79.0], [6.0], [8.0], [61.0], [88.0], [59.0], [91.0],
       [10.0], [11.0], [9.0], [120.0], [92.0], [12.0], [8.0], [13.0],
       [17.0], [18.0], [13.0], [14.0], [12.0], [176.0], [120.0], [182.0]]
```

That is, you want chunks of a long list. Then, just use slice syntax, ie, `list[0:2]` would be `[[68.0], [79.0], [6.0]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your data looks like it does in @JonClements answer, here's another approach using list comprehension.

```
[reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, l) for l in input_lists]
# [[68.0, 79.0, 6.0, 8.0, 61.0, 88.0, 59.0, 91.0],
#  [10.0, 11.0, 9.0, 120.0, 92.0, 12.0, 8.0, 13.0],
#  [17.0, 18.0, 13.0, 14.0, 12.0, 176.0, 120.0, 182.0]]
```

Comment: The only problem is that this list is part of a for loop so if I try your suggestion then `input_lists[0]` returns (not a horizontal list as I provided above):
68.0
10.0
17.0